# How to set margin in tabbar Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbar

Hi I have Tabbed Page how can I set margin in tabbar Xamarin forms in Xamarin Forms.I give link on my app.There I add 2 page,but when I want to add 5 pages I want to reduce gaps between pictures.Please help me

My code

https://github.com/kamenskyh/customTabbedPage

[image]

Comment: What do you mean to reduce gaps between pictures?You don't want tabs evenly spaced across the width?

Comment: Yes. I want to reduce the spacing and make them different.Can I do it?

Comment: You could try to change the `app:tabMode="scrollable"` in your `Resource/layout/Tabbar.xml` in Android project. Is that what you want ？